# Property not initialized on SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created a object (button) visually in MenuScene.sks, also assigned a name (to the button) and set a custom class to MenuScene.sks. In MenuScene.swift I try to initialize my property with object created before but it is not found.

```
import SpriteKit

class MenuScene: SKScene {

    var newGameButtonNode: SKSpriteNode!
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        if var newGameButtonNode = self.childNode(withName: "newGameButton") as? SKSpriteNode {
            print("found")
        } else {
            print("not found")
        }
    }
}
```

Following code outputs "not found", what else should be checked/corrected?

Answer (score 0):

Try run this code instead:

```
import SpriteKit
```

class MenuScene: SKScene {

`// Visuals
var newGameButtonNode: SKSpriteNode!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    // Init visuals
    newGameButtonNode = self.childNode(withName: "//newGameButtonNode") as? SKSpriteNode

    // Check for node excistense
    if let node = self.newGameButtonNode {
        print("It's working!")
    } else {
        print("It's not working..")
    }
  }
}`